# Observable property not updating in test using Angular / Mocha

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocha.js, observable

I am testing a component I wrote that loads a local JSON file, all is great and working well but my tests aren't going so smoothly! In my component I have the following that loads a JSON list of items I use in my projects:

```
public softwareList: Observable<any>;

public ngOnInit() {
    this.softwareList = this.http.get('path/to/software.json').map((res: any) => {
        const respJson = res.json();
        return respJson.about.dependencies.software;
    });
}
```

In my test I mock the results from the JSON and the http.get call and all looks good - here's my test code below...

```
// here's the mock...
const mockResponse = {
    about: {
      dependencies: {
        heading: 'Software Dependencies',
        explaination: 'Blah blah blah',
        software: [
          {
            name: 'Angular & Angular Material',
            url: 'https://github.com/angular'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  };


// here's my test
it('should load the Software Dependencies list', async(() => {
    const instance = componentFixture.componentInstance;
    const spyHttpGet = sinon.spy(instance.http, 'get');

    instance.ngOnInit();

    expect(spyHttpGet.calledOnce).to.be.eq(true);
    expect(spyHttpGet.withArgs'path/to/software.json').calledOnce).to.be.eq(true);

    instance.softwareList.subscribe((res:any) => {
      console.log(res); // [Object{name: 'Angular & Angular Material', url: 'https://github.com/angular'}]
      expect(instance.softwareList).to.be.eq(mockResponse.about.dependencies.software);
    });
  }));
```

Now the final test here, the one in the subscription callback fails. I get the following error

> AssertionError: expected { Object (_isScalar, observers, ...) } to
>   equal [ Array(1) ]

From the console.log I see the following:

```
[Object{name: 'Angular & Angular Material', url: 'https://github.com/angular'}]
```

This is what I expect! It is also what I expect the value of the `instance.softwareList`to be! I don't understand why my `instance.softwareList` isn't updating to the value that is returned by the `subscribe`? What am I missing, why isn't `instance.softwareList = [{name: 'Angular & Angular Material', url: 'https://github.com/angular'}]`?

Any explanations would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You affect the observable to softwareList in your ngOnInit: `this.softwareList = this.http.get`

So softwareList have an observable signature:

> Object (_isScalar, observers, ...)

To pass your test you could assert the response of the observable :

```
expect(res).to.be.eq(mockResponse.about.dependencies.softwar‌​e);
```